# checkstyle JavadocType only on classes/interfaces/enums

Tags: java, maven-plugin, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am trying to configure the checkstyle rules, which will verify the classes, interfaces and enums to mandate the javadocs with the below configurations:

```
<module name="JavadocStyle">
    <property name = "checkEmptyJavadoc" value="true"/>
    <property name ="checkFirstSentence" value="false"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, ENUM_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF, METHOD_DEF"/>
```

But they are getting reflected i.e. even though I didn't provided any java docs at class level still the check-style is getting passed instead of giving an error about the missing java docs.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> which will verify the classes, interfaces and enums to mandate the javadocs

First off, I recommend you don't use `JavadocStyle` for this but instead use `MissingJavadocType` as this is the only purpose this check is designed for. It is possible in a future update `JavadocStyle` will not do this anymore since it is duplicating what `MissingJavadocType` does. For methods use `MissingJavadocMethod`.

Regardless, for either check you use, you must specify the correct `scope` that you want it to pick up classes. If it is incorrect it won't trigger on all cases.

Example with violation on the enumeration but not the class because of different scopes:

```
$ cat TestClass.java
public enum TestEnum {}
private class TestClass {}

$ cat TestConfig.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

    <module name="TreeWalker">
<module name="MissingJavadocType">
    <property name="scope" value="public"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="CLASS_DEF, ENUM_DEF, INTERFACE_DEF"/>
</module>
    </module>
</module>

$ java -jar checkstyle-8.32-all.jar -c TestConfig.xml TestClass.java
Starting audit...
[ERROR] TestClass.java:1: Missing a Javadoc comment. [MissingJavadocType]
Audit done.
Checkstyle ends with 1 errors.
```